Hilfe bei Satzstellung - Reihenfolge "Zeitergänzung, Subjekt, Prädikat,..." möglich?
Arbeitsblatt 6. Klasse Deutsch: Bilde Sätze nach den folgenden Mustern

Zeitergänzung, Subjekt, Prädikat, Akkusativobjekt, Ortsergänzung

Wie kann das Subjekt hier vor dem Prädikat kommen? Uns fallen nur Sätze ein wie

In der Nacht der Junge liest ein Buch unter der Decke.

Das klingt für uns aber eher nach Meister Yoda :-) Gibt es vernünftige deutsche Sätze, die diese Reihenfolge liefern?

Ich möchte die Behauptung aufstellen, dass diese Reihenfolge unmöglich ist.
Im Deutschen steht das Verb fast immer an zweiter Stelle. Ausnahmen davon sind beispielsweise der Imperativ (Die Befehlsform). Aber auch dann steht das Verb niemals an dritter Stelle.
Ich gehe nach Hause. --> Geh nach Hause!
Wenn die Zeitergänzung am Satzanfang steht muss das Verb darauf folgen. Das Verb ist in der Regel Teil des Prädikats, weil das Prädikat beschreibt, was das Subjekt tut bzw. was mit ihm passiert (passiv).
Die richtige Reihenfolge für euren Beispielsatz wäre:

In der Nacht liest der Junge ein Buch unter der Decke.

Heißt, ich vermute eine von zwei Möglichkeiten:

Das ist nicht die vollständige Aufgabenstellung
Die Aufgabenstellung ist falsch


Danke. Dann gehe ich davon aus, dass hier "Die Aufgabenstellung ist falsch" zutrifft. Oder es war eine Fangfrage und man sollte erkennen, dass das nicht funktioniert...
